# Earliest Time in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to find the earliest time in an excel file based on the date AND the time in Excel for a specific set of rows.

So if I have these entries:

[image]

And I want to get the earliest time in the subset of row 1, 2, and 4.

The earliest time would be row 4 in the subset. What would the command be for getting the row number for this kind of problem?

Comment: when using a discontinued range, among multiple columns, no formula can do. How do you enter the subset rows in the formula? Only a macro can do that. Is that your goal?

Comment: @scavenger - you are wrong.  It's a prime example of simply using a pivot table.

Comment: my bad, i assumed wrongly his example was a short one, and thought that Ehren wanted something automated for larger sets. Pivot was the right answer for 3 factors. sorry i forgot about it lol

Comment: So how set are you on specifically **excluding** row 3 from the equation? Also, it's confusing if either you want a minimum for each unique date *or* if you want a single minimum value just for the subset of rows you have defined? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

That's what pivot tables are for:

[image]